# Error - Python vlc binding for mac

Tags: python, libvlc

As per instruction mentioned in https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings#Download, I took the vlc.py module from the Git repository (http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/wxvlc.py;hb=HEAD) and pasted in pycharm. Pycharm shows unresolved references for the following methods:

```
libvlc_video_get_chapter_description(..)
libvlc_video_get_title_description(..)
libvlc_audio_output_device_id(..)
libvlc_audio_output_device_longname(..)
libvlc_audio_output_device_count(..)
...
```

Can someone please suggest what I'm missing here ?

Comment: did you import them? where have you pasted vlc.py?

Comment: vlc.py itself has a main method. I have pasted vlc.py like any other code and tried running it. Before even running, I have errors shown by pycharm as mentioned above.

Comment: understood. I have look the codes of vlc.py. I didn't found any definitions of the above functions. So pycharm was right. You should ask the author about that.

Comment: generate.py (http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generator/generate.py;h=c0808a6e5ba8dd700129df391a2557a78c170e74;hb=HEAD) lists these functions too. Somehow, not available in vlc.py

Comment: I looked at the code of vlc.py. The script load some functions from the vlc libraries (see `def find_lib` and `def _Cfunction`).  So you must install VLC before using it through Python. The vlc libraries are written in C . Pycharm can find only references from `import`. So the messages of Pycharm were right. But you should possible run the script without problem

Comment: import vlc, 
instance = vlc.Instance(), 
print str(instance) # prints None; instance.media_player_new() - (libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.) 
Not sure where am I doing wrong with vlc.py

Comment: which o.s do you have?

Comment: OSX Yosemite 10.10.5